# keep each fragment selected inner ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I implement the same fragment of 100 in ViewPager on my application. The fragment rather large display data from the server. When I put the code `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit (100)`, the app feels very heavy. Therefore, I use the way: remove `setOffscreenPageLimit` and invoke a method to check the data on the server and displays it when the fragment was selected. But when this happens: when Fragment "1" was chosen, then to fragment "2", back to fragment "1", Fragment "1" will repeat the activity. My question is how to keep the activity of each fragment is selected or when returning to the fragment that was selected at the last condition? Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

if you remove setOffscreenPageLimit, The way to keep the activity of each fragment is store the state data of fragment in:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putData("key", fragmentData);
    }
```

when you leave it, when you back again, you update the fragment by the state data you have stored.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           fragmentData  = savedInstanceState.getData("key", defaultData);
    }
```

You should use some fragments in a viewpager, do not use too more. think about use a fragment and display many views, data in it.

Answer (score 0):

> setOffscreenPageLimit : Set the number of pages that should be
>   retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in
>   an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the
>   adapter when needed.

Don't setOffscreenPageLimit too large, because the view pager will keep the page active so your app will run slowly. And when you remove setOffscreenPageLimit, this setting defaults to 1. It means that pages beyond this limit (1) will be recreated from the adapter when needed. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)